# JOIN lang table with UNION

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with JOIN main table "cities" and lang table "cities_lang"

I use this way, but UNION ignore my INDEXes.

```sql
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
FROM `cities` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `cities_lang` `AIlang` WHERE lang = "ru"
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM `cities_lang` `AIlang` WHERE lang = "en"
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM `cities_lang` `AIlang` WHERE lang != "ru" AND lang != "en" 
  ) AS one  
  GROUP BY one.city__id
) AS AIlang ON (`AIlang`.`city__id`=`t`.`id`) 
WHERE (sort_no IS NOT NULL AND type = 1) 
ORDER BY sort_no
```

http://prntscr.com/pb5k27

Can you offer me some way to get row from lang table in language with sort I need

Comment: Try this. It may be helpful to you. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133972/mysql-query-with-union-doesnt-use-index

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not designed to unduplicate i assume thats why you are using `SELECT * ... ` with `GROUP BY one.city__id` which is invalid SQL and should error annyway when sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is running.. ..

Comment: as your SQL is most likey wrong.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `UNION`s you can just join `cities_lang` table once and include your conditions in the `ON`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `cities` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cities_lang` AS AIlang ON (`AIlang`.`city__id`=`t`.`id`) 
  AND (
    lang IN("ru","en") OR
    (lang != "ru" AND lang != "en")
  )
WHERE (sort_no IS NOT NULL AND type = 1) 
ORDER BY sort_no
```

I don't know if this will address your question about index access because it's a complex `JOIN` condition now, but run the `EXPLAIN` and see what it says.

Like the previous commentor mentioned, your `SQL` is a bit unwieldy with the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *`.  You may want to tighten it up by only selecting the columns you want to project.